# How to set the text of the button in the webview?

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I'm currently working on **WebView** in Android, I wanted to change the text of the button inside the WebView.

I tried these line of codes but its not working

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:document.getElementByName('btn').value = 'test';");
```

and this...

```
String str="test";
webView.loadUrl("javascript: setButtonText(strbtext,str)");
```

Here's the sample of my code

in onCreate where I set enable the Javascript and load the html

```
webView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.wbview);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

and here's the method where I want to change the text of the button programmatically

```
 @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        if (Activity.canReadCardWithCamera()) {
            //set text true
        } else {
            //set text false
        }
```

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script scr="index.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>
<input id="btn" type="button" value="default" onclick="doSomething();" />
</body>
</html>
```

**index.js**

```
function setButtonText(strbtext,str){
  document.findElementById(btn).value=str;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try :

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:setButtonText('test', 'test')");
```

EDIT:

Also, I found a bug in `setButtonText()` js function. That would be like this :

```
function setButtonText(strbtext,str){
  document.getElementById("btn").value=str;
}
```